# Displaying data labels on open xml charts in c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

We are using open xml for displaying bar graph in exl export but it is not showing labels on data like values above each bar. 
Here is the code i am using

```
BarChart barChart = plotArea.AppendChild<BarChart>(new BarChart(new BarDirection() { Val = new         EnumValue<BarDirectionValues>(BarDirectionValues.Column) },
                new BarGrouping() { Val = new EnumValue<BarGroupingValues>(BarGroupingValues.Clustered) }));
BarChartSeries barChartSeries = barChart.AppendChild<BarChartSeries>(new BarChartSeries(new Index()
                {
                    Val =
                        new UInt32Value(i)
                },
                    new Order() { Val = new UInt32Value(i) },
                    new SeriesText(new NumericValue() { Text = key })));
```

where key is data value for bar. But still it is not displaying. Can anyone tell where exactly have to put data label so that value labels should be visible on top of each bar in bar graph

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a DataLabels class, modify how you want them to look and append it to your series. Hope this helps

```
        C.DataLabels dataLabels2 = new C.DataLabels();

        C.TextProperties textProperties2 = new C.TextProperties();
        A.BodyProperties bodyProperties2 = new A.BodyProperties();
        A.ListStyle listStyle2 = new A.ListStyle();

        A.Paragraph paragraph2 = new A.Paragraph();

        A.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new A.ParagraphProperties();

        A.DefaultRunProperties defaultRunProperties2 = new A.DefaultRunProperties() { FontSize = 700 };

        A.SolidFill solidFill2 = new A.SolidFill();
        A.SchemeColor schemeColor2 = new A.SchemeColor() { Val = A.SchemeColorValues.Background1 };

        solidFill2.Append(schemeColor2);

        defaultRunProperties2.Append(solidFill2);

        paragraphProperties2.Append(defaultRunProperties2);
        A.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties2 = new A.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US" };

        paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
        paragraph2.Append(endParagraphRunProperties2);

        textProperties2.Append(bodyProperties2);
        textProperties2.Append(listStyle2);
        textProperties2.Append(paragraph2);
        C.ShowLegendKey showLegendKey2 = new C.ShowLegendKey() { Val = false };
        C.ShowValue showValue2 = new C.ShowValue() { Val = true };
        C.ShowCategoryName showCategoryName2 = new C.ShowCategoryName() { Val = false };
        C.ShowSeriesName showSeriesName2 = new C.ShowSeriesName() { Val = false };
        C.ShowPercent showPercent2 = new C.ShowPercent() { Val = false };
        C.ShowBubbleSize showBubbleSize2 = new C.ShowBubbleSize() { Val = false };
        C.ShowLeaderLines showLeaderLines2 = new C.ShowLeaderLines() { Val = false };

        dataLabels2.Append(textProperties2);
        dataLabels2.Append(showLegendKey2);
        dataLabels2.Append(showValue2);
        dataLabels2.Append(showCategoryName2);
        dataLabels2.Append(showSeriesName2);
        dataLabels2.Append(showPercent2);
        dataLabels2.Append(showBubbleSize2);
        dataLabels2.Append(showLeaderLines2);


        barChartSeries2.Append(dataLabels2);
```